# Show and hide child HTML tag based on button click event

Tags: html, css

this is my code:

```
        <div id="templatemo_menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="http://www.templatemo.com" target="_parent">Templates</a></li>-->
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="last">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="http://www.templatemo.com" target="_parent">Templates</a></li>-->
                    <li><a href="#">Leave</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Complaint</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="last">Resignation</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

now when employee visits my home page without login in to my site then i want to display this on my menu bar:

```
         <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="http://www.templatemo.com" target="_parent">Templates</a></li>-->
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="last">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
```

and i want to hide this from my menu bar:

```
    <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="http://www.templatemo.com" target="_parent">Templates</a></li>-->
                    <li><a href="#">Leave</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Complaint</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="last">Resignation</a></li>
                </ul>
```

but when employee login in to my site then i want to display this on my menu bar  on my button click event:

```
    <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="http://www.templatemo.com" target="_parent">Templates</a></li>-->
                    <li><a href="#">Leave</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Complaint</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="last">Resignation</a></li>
                </ul>
```

and i want to hide this from my menu bar on button click event:

- Home
- Login
  Templates</a></li>-->
- About
- Contact Us

can any one suggest me how to do that???

Comment: Have you tried using JS cookies? When the employee signs in, you can check for a cookie and show the other options based on the cookies' presence.

Comment: but how to do this in asp.net with c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you prefer using JavaScript then solution is after click on login:

```
document.querySelector('#templatemo_menu ul:nth-child(1)').style.display='none';
document.querySelector('#templatemo_menu ul:nth-child(2)').style.display='block';
```

and if guest user without login go with

```
document.querySelector('#templatemo_menu ul:nth-child(2)').style.display='none';
document.querySelector('#templatemo_menu ul:nth-child(1)').style.display='block';
```

**Note:** But You might want to go for server side solution for checking session or cookie since JavaScript would not work, when user refreshes page.

Comment: thank u so much for replying.thank u once again.but can i do this in code behind file that is in .cs file in asp.net with C#???

Comment: I guess yes JavaScript is supported with every language, but I am not right person to ask about C#, I would recommend you to do some research on that.

Answer (score 0):

A trivial solution would be to harness jQuery's $.click() method to detect when your relevant tag has been clicked, then apply a styling which displays your menu. Or better yet, use jQuery's $.toggle to hide and show the menu based on alternating click events, applying and removing the same styling.

If you could place your site into something like a JSFiddle, it would be much simpler for us to see exactly what your markup represents and how to help. Best of luck!

Comment: thank u so so much for showing ur interest in my problem.i am developing my site in asp.net with C# and i want to do this in my code behind file that is .cs file on button click event.